# CSS typing animation not working for Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

I have been trying to fix my CSS type-writing animation for Firefox tonight - no success so far. The Chrome codes works tho. What am I missing guys?

```
.css-typing
{
    width: 680px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
    -o-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    -moz-animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
    }


@keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
    }

@-moz-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
    }

@-webkit-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
    }
```

The div which has to be defined by this code looks like this:

```
<div class='css-typing'>This text will pop up using an typewriting effect</div>
```

Does anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Beyond the fact that the `div` doesn't have the `.css-typing`?

Comment: typo... like mentioned, it works on chrome so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `to` part of the `@keyframes` block, and you also need to set the width of the element: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/vtdyuju4/

```
.css-typing {
    width: 360px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
    -o-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    -moz-animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
}


@keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
        to { width: 360px; } 
    }

@-moz-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
        to { width: 360px; } 
    }

@-webkit-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
        to { width: 360px; } 
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to work =/ My firefox version is up-2-date.

Comment: I tested it in Firefox 51 on Ubuntu 16.01, and it worked. Are you sure there isn't something you're overlooking?

Comment: I'm checking right now. Fiddle code works for me, yet my code doesn't seem to do anything on firefox.
Maybe it's a wordpress thing, I'm not sure. Trying to figure this out.

Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: Maybe set some of the properties using `!important`

Answer (score 0):

W3C recommends for best browser support that a "from" and a "to" are both defined inside `@keyframes`. Try changing your code to this:

```
.css-typing
{
    width: 680px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
    -o-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    -moz-animation: type 3s steps(55, end);
    }


@keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; },
        to {width:680px}
    }

@-moz-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; },
        to {width:680px}
    }

@-webkit-keyframes type
    {
        from { width: 0; }
        to {width:680px}
    }
```